# Adding a custom html and js Circular Nav Menu to Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have found this nice looking circular navigation:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/comment-page-5/#comment-461066

and would really like to add it to my wordpress page. 
I tried appending the css to the style.css of the child-theme and also appended the js to the custom.js file. I think I also need to reference the font-awesome font icons somewhere but I just don't know how to do it. I also tried adding the links to the header with the Header and Footer plugin but with no luck.

1) So the questions are how to make this particular navigation work?
2) How to migrate some html contents to wordpress in general?

Thanks!

Saldtch

Comment: i got everything working except for those font icons. Any help?

Comment: anyway :) haha, i just copied all the contents of the reference files to the style css and that works.